# Do Advaitins believe in Brahma tarka?

Tags: philosophy, advaita, adi-shankaracharya, dvaita

In Mahabharata Tatparya Nirnaya 9.135 we find the mention of Brahma Tarka which the Davitins believe in. Do the Advaitins believe in Brahma tarka too?

Comment: What is Brahma Tarka? Do you have any links that explain?

Comment: Brahma tarka is used in Mahabharata tatpariya narinaya 9:135

Comment: Ok updated the Q with that info.

Comment: I have given sir